# Nodejs: load javascript from external file containing functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to load javascript object from a file on my filesystem using Nodejs application.

Sample object stored in filesystem file ('myOwnFunction.js'):

```
exports.myOwnFunction = {
    "var2": "My value1",
    "var2": 100,
    "var3": true,
    "var4": function(abc) {
        var var5 = "some other value";
        runOtherFunction(var5)
    }
}
```

So, in the application itself, I would like to "load" several object like the sample above.

```
fs.readdir("./", function (err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) { // so loading all js files in folder
        var foo = require( "./"+file ).myOwnFunction;
    });
});
```

As a consequence, the script return the following error message:

> ReferenceError: runOtherFunction is not defined

I guess this is absolutely normal ; a question of (a)synchroneous and also because "runOtherFunction" is not available on the 'myOwnFunction.js' file.

Could you give me clues how to proceed or any alternative solution.
I'm quite sure I'm doing this the wrong way - but I'm bit lost..

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you see the error as soon as you've included the file, or when you attempt to execute the function assigned to `var4`?

Comment: This also might be a closure issue.  Sure, your 'requiring' a certain file, however, your immediately losing the scope of it as the loop iterates.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: it seems the errors appears where the file is 'required'.
So, I guess tier1 is having a clue.. Will check how closure works.

Comment: Where are you expecting `runOtherFunction` to come from?

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I expect function to be set on the script/application which is loading the external javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are exporting your modules is a little weird. I don't know it's wrong per se, but it doesn't follow node.js conventions. Try this:

myOwnFunction.js:

```
module.exports = function() {
    "var2": "My value1",
    "var2": 100,
    "var3": true,
    "var4": function(abc) {
        var var5 = "some other value";
        runOtherFunction(var5)
    }
});
```

In the file you want to use this function:

```
myOwnFunction = require('./myOwnFunction');

fs.readdir("./", function (err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) { // so loading all js files in folder
        var foo = require( "./"+file ).myOwnFunction;
    });
});
```

Comment: Node is very free form, lots of code styles are permissible, but perhaps not wise. Checkout Node School's tutorial ['learnyounode'](http://nodeschool.io/#learnyounode) for getting familiar with common conventions.